# What is a function type used for?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

Given the following two `typedef`s:

```
typedef void (*pftype)(int);

typedef void ftype(int);
```

I understand that the first defines `pftype` as a pointer to a function that takes one `int` parameter and returns nothing, and the second defines `ftype` as a function type that takes one `int` parameter and returns nothing. I do not, however, understand what the second might be used for.

I can create a function that matches these types:

```
void thefunc(int arg)
{
    cout << "called with " << arg << endl;
}
```

and then I can create pointers to this function using each:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pftype pointer_one = thefunc;
    ftype *pointer_two = thefunc;

    pointer_one(1);
    pointer_two(2);
}
```

When using the function type, I have to specify that I'm creating a pointer. Using the function pointer type, I do not. Either can be used interchangeably as a parameter type:

```
void run_a_thing_1(ftype pf)
{
    pf(11);
}

void run_a_thing_2(pftype pf)
{
    pf(12);
}
```

What use, therefore, is the function type? Doesn't the function pointer type cover the cases, and do it more conveniently?

Comment: @nhahtdh: The question is, why are there function types as well as pointer-to-function types?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Indeed, as Mike says, the question is about function types. I know why pointer-to-function types exist.

Comment: Mostly for "cosmetic" effect (make code easier to read). You can typedef anything you like (as long as it is valid). Between the 2 cases, I'm not sure which is better, though.

Comment: and see this one related question/answers: [click on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480248/function-references)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As well as the use you point out (the underlying type of a pointer or reference to a function), the most common uses for function types are in function declarations:

```
void f(); // declares a function f, of type void()
```

for which one might want to use a `typedef`:

```
typedef void ft(some, complicated, signature);
ft f;
ft g;

// Although the typedef can't be used for definitions:
void f(some, complicated, signature) {...}
```

and as template parameters:

```
std::function<void()> fn = f;  // uses a function type to specify the signature
```

Comment: Great answer. I never thought of using a typedef this way.

Comment: Ah, the key there is function _declarations_. They (apparently) cannot be used in function _definitions_.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed, that's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider this

```
template<typename T>
void f(T*);
```

Since we want it to accept function pointers, by pattern matching the T becomes a function type.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that I think `function_t *fptr ...` is clearer than `funcptr_t fptr...`. The first form stated that it must be a pointer type, which is clearer than anything, including the name `funcptr_t`.