# std::tr1::function and the template value it accepts

Tags: c++, tr1

I was reviewing some code and came upon a line similar to:

```
std::tr1::function<bool (int, int)>(//etc...
```

The syntax for the template type, `bool (int, int)` was unfamiliar to me.  Based on Googling, in the case of `std::tr1::function` it seems this syntax is used to define a function's return type and parameters.  That makes sense, but why does that syntax work?  As far as I know, C++ templates can only specify types?

I tried to instantiate an instance of the type in code as:

```
bool (int, int) test;
```

As I expected, the statement failed to compile.  At the very least, the syntax would need to be something like:
    bool (test)(int, int);

Is `bool (int, int)` treated as a C++ type?  Any tips on reconciling this in my mind?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Function types make perfectly good types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a function type.

You can't create instances of it, but you can create pointers to them and typedefs.

This question has some insight: [What is a function type used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590084/what-is-a-function-type-used-for)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Pubby.  Until now, I never knew that one could specify unnamed function types in C++.  I usually used typedef: `typedef bool (* FnPtr)(int, int);`  I confirmed that I can simply pass "bool (int, int)" as the template type and it works as expected -- are template types the only place where these un-named function types can be used?

Comment: @AdamForume I don't know of any other practical uses for it.