# Can I create reference to function?

Tags: c++, reference, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480248/function-references)

I found this code in a book ,

`typedef int (&foo)(int,int);`

What does it mean ? Is this reference to a function ? If yes, Why is it used for ? 
And how is it different from pointer to a function like this .

`typedef int (*foo)(int,int);`

Is this just an enhancement in C++ which is not in C ?

**EDIT** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int f (int , int ) {return 0;}
int main() {
    int (&foo)(int,int) = f;
    int (*fp)(int,int) = f;
    std::cout<<typeid(foo).name()<<std::endl<<typeid(fp).name();
    return 0;
}
```

When I print type of `foo` and `fp` it gives something like this :

FiiiE
PFiiiE

What is `E` in the last. and why `foo` is `F` while `fp` is `PF` ?

Comment: my C/C++ powers are weak, however doesnt the "&" approximate to "contents of" and "*" mean "address of" ?  .. Just Read the replies to my comment - thanks for that guys, more reading needed.

Comment: @FreudianSlip, Not in this context. & can be either that (except you mixed them up), a bitwise and, or a reference.

Comment: @FreudianSlip In C++, `&` can also be used as a type qualifier to declare a reference type.

Comment: Like all references, you can't (easily) *not* set it. Its a reference, and just like all references, once set, it isn't gonna change. A pointer on the other hand... I think you'd be best served to study pointers vs references in C++ *first*.

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple

Comment: C++ enhancements for C almost always are not in C.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Yeah I am new to C++ , but wanted to know Is it same as we use references in case of variables or something else

Comment: @Omkant no worries at all, I've seen your posts and answers, and was a little surprised this one took you back a minute. H2CO3's linked article is a good read, btw.

Comment: Btw edited my question though .. What have I tried