# What's the difference between function with dereference and without dereference

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, dereference

What's the difference between f1, (*f1), f2, (*f2) ?
and what's the difference between (function) and (&function) ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function (char *s) {
    cout << s << endl;
}

int main () {
    void (*f1) (char*) = &function;
    void (*f2) (char*) = function;

    f1 ("f1 function without dereference.");
    (*f1) ("f1 function with dereference.");
    f2 ("f2 function without dereference.");
    (*f2) ("f2 function with dereference.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The name of a function automatically turns into a function pointer, even without the explicit `&`, which is the "address of" operator, btw.

Comment: Nothing ... they are the exact same.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the difference between f1, (*f1), f2, (*f2) ?

`f1` and `f2` are function pointers. `(*f1)` and `(*f2)` are references to functions. What's the difference between function pointers and function references? Extremely little, as they are both callable with the exact same syntax. However, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480248/function-references) for a more in-depth explanation of function references.

> and what's the difference between (function) and (&function) ?

`function` is a function. `&function` is a pointer to a function. One extremely minor difference here relates to the fact that you can bind a function reference to a function, but not to a function pointer.

```
void (&fref1)(char*) = function; // compiles
void (&fref2)(char*) = &function; // does not compile
```

Again, see the linked question for possible reasons you might use a function reference (there aren't many).